# Tab movement in shoes

Tags: ruby, shoes, tab-ordering

I have a problem I have a:

```
stack {
  flow {
    para "Enter text:"
    edit_line
  }
edit_box
}
```

(simplified version). When user is on edit_line and presses
tab, I want it to move to edit_box control (currently, it just
loses focus).

```
 Thanks,

   Juraj.
```

Comment: Your simplified example works for me.  I'm running Shoes 2 "Raisins" (build 1134) on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this only works on linux (and maybe windows)

It is a problem with the way the native widgets are rendered on other platforms.  Maybe it can be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I had a go @ the example listed above and am experiencing the expected behaviour you describe.

What platform are you running your app on?

Cheers,

Kunal